# Freeform Contact form disallowed key characters

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, channel-form

first time using the Solspace freeform add on. When i test out the contact form i get a "disallowed key characters"

here is my code..

```
    {exp:freeform:form form_name="contact" required="first_name|user_message" return="contact|contact_us" admin_notify="pete@pbwebdeisngs.co.uk"}   
    <div class="grid_8 prefix_2 suffix_2">
        <div class="block_green">
            <h4 class="white title1 space3">Email me here!</h4>
            <label for="{first_name}">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="{first_name}"/>
            <br />
            <br />

            <label for="{email}">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="{email}"/>
            <br /><br />

            <label for="{user_message}">Message</label>
            <textarea name="{user_message}"></textarea>
            <br /><br />

            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Comment" name="submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

probably something stupid as usual but help would be appreciated

Thanks Peterp205

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="{email}"/>
```

This is why - you're posting an item whose *key* is an email address. EE treats this as malicious data (as it contains the `@` character).

What you meant to write was:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="{email}" />
```

Same goes for all your other inputs - you have `name` confused with `value`, and your `value`s are all missing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Derek's answer, try changing `return="contact|contact_us"` to `return="contact/contact_us"`, or some other URL (by the way, return="" should hold a URL, absolute or relative).